# 文字列からのダミー変数作成

Tags: python, pandas

家の特徴を示す情報を持つ変数xより、シェアハウスと、バルコニーのある物件の場合に１とする
次のような変数shareとbalconyを作成したいと考えています。

```
index share balcony
0       1       1
1       0       1
2       1       0
3       1       0
```

変数名を示すリスト var_nameと、キーワードを示すリスト var_tango
より、目的の変数を作成したいと考えています。
次のようなコードを作成しているのですが、
nameという変数が作成されるのみで、
ループに問題があるようです。

基本的なことが分かっていないのだと思いますが、
解決する方法をご教示頂きたく、よろしくお願いします。

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['バルコニーのあるシェアハウス',
           '南にバルコニーあり',
           'シェアハウス',
           '角部屋、シェアハウス']})

var_name = ['share','balcony']
var_tango = ['シェア','バルコニー']

for name in var_name:
    df["name"]=0  # dfにvar_nameの要素の変数名を作成する
    for tango in var_tango:
        if "tango" in str(df['ｘ'].iat[i]):　# x内にtangoの要素が入っていた場合に下記を実行
            df["name"].iat[i]= 1
```

Comment: `numpy.where()` を使って `df['share'] = numpy.where(df['x'].str.contains('シェア'), 1, 0)` など。

Comment: if文を使わずに、このようにも書くことができるのですね。勉強になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リストをまとめてループ処理できる`zip`と文字列を含むかどうかを判定する`str.contains`を使って次のようにかけます。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['バルコニーのあるシェアハウス',
           '南にバルコニーあり',
           'シェアハウス',
           '角部屋、シェアハウス']})

var_name = ['share','balcony']
var_tango = ['シェア','バルコニー']

for (name, tango) in zip(var_name, var_tango):
    df[name] = df['x'].str.contains(tango).astype(int)
```

`zip`を使わずに書けば以下のようになります。この問題では、`for`の二重ループにするのはよくないです。

```
for i in range(len(var_name)):
    df[var_name[i]] = df['x'].str.contains(var_tango[i]).astype(int)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。このように簡潔に書くことができるとは、驚きです。